# What's wrong with my let syntax?

Tags: scheme

What's wrong with my let syntax in scheme?

error: Cannot read property 'car' of undefined

```
(define (test x)

    (let (a 1))

    )
```

Comment: Syntax is `(let ( <binding>* ) <form>* )` where each `<binding>` is `(<variable> <form>)`.  You need `(let ((a 1)) )` instead.

Answer (score 3):

The correct syntax is:

```
(let ((a value1)
      (b value2))
   exp)
```

You forgot an opening bracket.